# Deprecating renamed method with multiple arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, deprecated

I wanted to update the naming of the following method for Swift 3:

```
public func imageWithUrl(url: String, placeholderNamed: String) {
    if let image = UIImage(named: placeholderNamed) {
        imageWithUrl(url: url, placeholder: image)
    } else {
        imageWithUrl(url: url)
    }
}
```

to

```
public func image(url: String, placeholderNamed: String) {
```

So I deprecated the old method with this:

```
@available(*, deprecated: 1.8, renamed: "image(url:, placeholder:")
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

> 'renamed' argument of 'available' attribute must be an operator, identifier, or full function name, optionally prexied by a type name

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was having a problem with the `renamed:` part. In order to fix that, just change it to

```
@available(*, deprecated: 1.8, renamed: "image(url:placeholder:)")
```

Comment: This is not entirely clear in the docs (or at least not apparent), but the construction of the string literal argument given for `renamed` follows quite strict rules; in the case above using a _"full function name"_ (which, imo, _could_ be specified more clearly in the docs). Your answer here fixes the argument, so it does now indeed follow the rule for what a _"full function name"_ is (no separation by commas).

Comment: It still doesn't move the arguments unless the parameters align exactly apart from the name though. Pity.