# How to deprecate/rename a swift function using @available. Function has more than one parameters

Tags: swift

this is my old function

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellState: CellState)
```

but i want this to be renamed to this function

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath)
```

How do I do this using @available?

`@available(*, unavailable, renamed: "what do i put in here?")`

Comment: Put the name of your new method, no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116200/deprecating-renamed-method-with-multiple-arguments ?

Comment: I added a link to another question. Try to pu `"calendar(_:cellState:indexPath:)"`.